# Monitor.TryEnter doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Part of my code-behind:

```
object _sync = new object();

private async void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(_sync)) return;

    Trace.Write("taken...");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    Trace.WriteLine(" done");

    Monitor.Exit(_sync);
}
```

Output (pressing several times in less than 5 seconds):

```
taken...taken...taken... done
done
done
```

How-come?? the `_sync` lock is never being taken, why?

Comment: Frankly, mixing `Monitor` with `await` is a recipe for disaster... which thread is it going to using at each point, for example?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MarcGravell, it does work with `Thread`s but not with `Task`s? why? I mean, in this example, does it matter which `Thread` it is? the `_sync` should have been taken on the first `Monitor.TryEnter`, but it wasn't, that's what I don't get

Comment: @Tal indeed, I would expect `TryEnter` to return `true` here; which prompts the question: is there any other code synchronizing against `_sync`? Or using `_sync` in some way?

Comment: @MarcGravell - no, it's a refined testing code, just to demonstrate this specific behavior

Comment: @Tal back to basics: what makes you think it is "never being taken"? The output shows "taken...taken...taken..." ?

Comment: AH! I see what you are describing - yeah, that is an expectation fail. `Monitor` is re-entrant; the UI thread can take the same lock **any number of times** (any thread that already has the lock can automatically take it again and again and again). Yet another reason why `Monitor` is the wrong tool here.

Comment: In this particular case, since `OnKeyDown` is supposed to be called by only one thread (the UI thread) why not simply use a boolean ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Mixing `Monitor` and `await` is... more than a little risky. It looks like what you are trying to do is to ensure it only runs once at a time. I suspect `Interlocked` may be simpler:

```
object _sync = new object();
int running = 0;
private async void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if(Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref running, 1, 0) != 0) return;

    Trace.Write("taken...");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    Trace.WriteLine(" done");

    Interlocked.Exchange(ref running, 0);
}
```

Note you might also want to think what happens if an error occurs etc; how does the value become reset? You can probably use `try`/`finally`:

```
if(Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref running, 1, 0) != 0) return;

try {
    Trace.Write("taken...");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    Trace.WriteLine(" done");
} finally {
    Interlocked.Exchange(ref running, 0);
}
```

Comment: But isn't the whole point of `Monitor` is `multithreading` synchronization? why should it work with `Thread`s but not with `Task`s?

Comment: @Tal different steps in an `async` pipeline can happen on different threads; `Monitor` won't do what you expect at the `Exit`.

Comment: As [Stephen Cleary noted above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410320/monitor-tryenter-doesnt-work#comment32298976_21410489), `Monitor.TryEnter`/`Monitor.Enter` will be successful if ran in the same thread... I missed that point...

Comment: @Tal: I wouldn't say "successful". ;) It will allow the code to enter the lock again, which is usually what you *don't* want.

Comment: Right, the recursive-thing... one more question, though - another suggestion, again by [Stephen Cleary above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21410489/587467), was to use `SemaphoreSlim`, what do you think about that?

Answer (score 18):

You can't use a thread-affine type like `Monitor` with `await`. In this particular case, you're always acquiring the lock on the same thread (the UI thread), and this type of lock permits recursive locking.

Try `SemaphoreSlim` instead (`WaitAsync` and `Release` instead of `Enter` and `Exit`):

```
SemaphoreSlim _sync = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

private async void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  await _sync.WaitAsync();

  Trace.Write("taken...");
  await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
  Trace.WriteLine(" done");

  _sync.Release();
}
```

Comment: But isn't the whole point of `Monitor` is multithreading synchronization?

Comment: You can't enter a monitor in two different threads. But you are entering a monitor in the same thread multiple times.

Comment: Ah... I missed that point... if I `Monitor.TryEnter`ed successfully on thread X, further `Monitor.TryEnter` attempts in that thread X will always be successful (until `Monitor.Exit`ed), right?

Comment: @Tal: Yes. That's what I mean by "recursive locking".

Comment: just one more question if I may - why not use `Interlocked` as [Marc Gravell suggested below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21410586/587467)?

Comment: The code using `SemaphoreSlim` will wait and execute one after another. The code using `Interlocked` will not execute if another one is already executing.

Comment: @StephenCleary this is a replacement for Monitor.Enter but not Monitor.TryEnter, or? When you press the key 100 times, this answer will call 100x task.delay one after each other. But the idea was to call it only once, and every other key after that, is ignored.

Answer (score 8):

You can't use `await` between `Monitor.TryEnter()` and `Monitor.Exit()` method calls.  After the `await`, the thread context might be different which would mean that the thread wouldn't have the `entered` the lock and therefore it would NOT be able to `exit` it.

In fact, the compiler will protect you if you use the `lock` keyword:

```
lock(_sync)
{
  await Task.Delay(...); // <- Compiler error...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Stephen Cleary's answer using the SemaphoreSlim changes the behavior because it queues the clicks instead of discarding them. The solution is to add a timeout of 0ms to .Wait(0) or .WaitAsync(0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.wait?view=net-6.0#system-threading-semaphoreslim-wait(system-int32)

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

private async void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_semaphoreSlim.Wait(0))
        return;

    try
    {
        Trace.Write("taken...");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        Trace.WriteLine(" done");
    }
    finally
    {
        _semaphoreSlim.Release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`TryEnter` will run on your gui thread. It's valid for a thread to acquire a monitor multiple times without blocking, it just has to release them the same number of times.

Your call to `Monitor.Exit` will run in the the context dictated by your`async` call. If it ends up running on a thread other than the thread that called `TryEnter` then it will fail to release the monitor.

So, you're acquiring the monitor on the same thread each time, which will never block, and you're releasing it on some other thread, that may work. That's why you're able to click rapidly within the 5 second window.

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that `TryEnter` will succeed if the **current thread** already acquired the lock. The `KeyDown` event will always fire on the Dispatcher thread, while a background thread is processing the wait and then enqueueing the unlock back on the dispatcher thread.